# SharePoint Online Default Form - Display Choice column as multi-select checkboxes

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, list-form, choice-field, default

I have a SharePoint Online list with a Default SP Form I'm customizing with json (not using PowerApps).  Is there a way I can display a multi-select Choice column as checkboxes, rather than a dropdown in the Default Form?  I figured json might be the answer, though I'm not sure how to write that.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a reference to this video: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Webinars-and-Video-Gallery/How-to-Create-Multi-select-Checkboxes-in-Power-Apps-for/td-p/1861362